# BlackBerry 10: Load GroupDataModel data into a JSON file?

Tags: blackberry-10

I have a ListView in QML using a cpp GroupDataModel that is created from a .json file in the assets folder. Items from this ListView are removed and added to. In cpp how do I get the GroupDataModel data into the JSON file?

I know there is this:

```
JsonDataAccess jda;
jda.save(huh?, "/app/native/assets/employees.json");
```

How do I get the GroupDataModel data into a QVariant to put in the first parameter of that function? I can't just stick my m_model GroupDataModel in there; it causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over your model with [`GroupDataModel::data()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-data-indexpath) and [`GroupDataModel::childCount()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-childcount-indexpath) to create your resulting QVariant, then store it. As far as I know, there's no automatic way to do this.

Edit: there is [one](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-tolistofmaps).

Comment: Thanks, last night I found it here too: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-tolistofmaps  There is a post on the BB dev forums with a quick "foreach" looper to get the pesky items in there and stuff them in a QVariant

Answer (score 0):

for loading groupdatamodel content in to json file, you have to do:

```
QList<QVariantMap> myList = m_model->toListOfMaps();
QVariantList membersList;
foreach(QVariantMap s, myList){
    membersList << s;
}
JsonDataAccess jda;     
jda.save(membersList,path);
```